# Passing form object to another method

Tags: c#, forms

Im trying to pass a form object from the method that creates it to one that will show it and set a few properties on it, instead of having the smae code in each button event. Im getting the error

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture' to
>   'ref System.Windows.Forms.Form'" and "The best overloaded method match for 'RWCStatTracker.Form1.showForm(ref System.Windows.Forms.Form)' has some invalid arguments"

These are occuring on line 70 in the button click event where it has `showForm(ref frm)`;

Below is code:

```
public void addToolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture frm = new RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture();
        showForm(ref frm);
    }

    public void showForm(ref Form frm)
    {
        frm.TopLevel = false; //set it's TopLevel to false

        Controls.Add(frm); //and add it to the parent Form
        frm.Show(); //finally display it

        frm.BringToFront(); //use this it there are Controls over your form.
    }
```

I've found many articles on google but none are really achieving what im trying to achieve

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: why it is showForm(ref Form frm) instead of showForm(Form frm)?

Comment: RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture  It is different type than Form ... it's obvious You cant pass it as an argument. Are You missing some cast ?

Comment: does FRMAddFixture inherit from Form?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee because it's passed as a refference - this part is ok it's not the problem

Comment: Just tried " showForm(Form frm)", give me the same error

Comment: @MajkeloDev: yes, I understand it is not the problem. It was a general query, since the ref parameter is not getting assigned inside showForm, so it seems useless.

Comment: What is the class definition of `FRMAddFixture`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution1:

Instead of:

```
public void showForm(ref Form frm)
```

Declare Your method like this:

```
public void showForm(ref RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture frm)
```

Solution2:

If RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture is "convertable" to a Form Type - Convert it before You pass it as a method parameter.

BTW.

Like it was said before - You don't need refs here, so You can get rid of this keyword in Your method.

Comment: and remove all unnecessary `ref`modifiers

Comment: No that defeats the purpose of having the showForm method as it wil be used by other button events which will be different to "FRMAddFixture" but I've managed to fix the issue by using showForm(frm); instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using C# Generic methods:

```
RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture frm = new RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture();

showForm<RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture>(ref frm);

 public static void showForm<T>(ref T frm) where T:class
        {
            if (typeof(T) is RWCStatTracker.Fixture.FRMAddFixture)
            {
                //add logic here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue by using showForm(frm); instead of showForm(ref frm);